# await useState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've been fighting with this code for days now and I'm still not getting it right.

The problem:
I'm working with a form that has a dropzone. On submit handler, I need to save the images' url in an array, but it's always returning as an empty array.

Declaring images array:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

Here I get the images' url and try to save them in the array:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {

      files.forEach(async(file)=> {
          const bodyFormData = new FormData();
          bodyFormData.append('image', file);
          setLoadingUpload(true);
          try {
            const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/uploads', bodyFormData, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
              },
            });
            setImages([...images,data])
            setLoadingUpload(false);
          } catch (error) {
            setErrorUpload(error.message);
            setLoadingUpload(false);
          }
      })
  }
```

Here I have the submitHandler function where I call the handleSubmit():

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit();
   dispatch(
        createCard(
          name,
          images,
        )
      );
}
```

I know it's because of the order it executes the code but I can't find a solution.
Thank you very much in advance!!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Issue

React state updates are asynchronously processed, but the state updater function itself isn't `async` so you can't wait for the update to happen. You can only ever access the state value from the current render cycle. This is why `images` is likely still your initial state, an empty array (`[]`).

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  handleSubmit(); // <-- enqueues state update for next render
  dispatch(
    createCard(
      name,
      images, // <-- still state from current render cycle
    )
  );
}
```

## Solution

I think you should rethink how you compute the next state of `images`, do a single update, and then use an `useEffect` hook to dispatch the action with the updated state value.

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  setLoadingUpload(true);
  try {
    const imagesData = await Promise.all(files.map(file => {
      const bodyFormData = new FormData();
      bodyFormData.append('image', file);
      return Axios.post('/api/uploads', bodyFormData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
      });
    }));
    setImages(images => [...images, ...imagesData]);
  } catch(error) {
    setErrorUpload(error.message);
  } finally {
    setLoadingUpload(false);
  }
}

const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  handleSubmit();
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  images.length && name && dispatch(createCard(name, images));
}, [images, name]);
```

Comment: Omg it worked!!!! And great explanation I got it now :) 
Thank you very very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent race-conditions, you could try to use the `setImages` with the current value as follows:

```
setImages(currentImages => [...currentImages, data])
```

This way, you will use exactly what is currently included in your state, since the `images` might not be the correct one in this case.

As another tip, instead of looping over your files, I would suggest you `map` the files, as in `files.map(...`. With this, you can map all file entries to a promise and at the end, merge them to one promise which contains all requests. So you can simply watch it a bit better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried that, but still not working :(
I put a console.log(data) before the setImages(currentImages => [...currentImages, data]) and a console.log(images) after it. The data returns "/uploads/1621487791667.jpg" but images is an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Just await your map function with an await Promise.all() function. This will resolve all promises and return the filled array