# useState doesn't update state by double click immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get info from an api but the useState() doesn't work correctly.
I have a work order grid by double click on each row I get the work order id then I should get the information from a specific api route to "workorder/:id" and display them. but when I try to console log the information by double click on a row I get "undefined"

here is my code:

```
  const gridOptions = {
    onRowDoubleClicked: openWorkOrder,
  }
function openWorkOrder(row) {
        const workOrderId = row.data.id
        navigate(`workorder/${workOrderId}`)
        fetch(`baseURL/api/Gages/WorkFlow/GetProductDetailByOrderId?id=${workOrderId}`)
          .then((result) => result.json())
          .then((data) => props.setDetails(data))
        console.log(props.details)
    }
```

`const [details, setDetails] = useState()` is defined in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

The `useState` in React is an asynchronous hook ([Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)).
When you call useState, it doesn't update state immediately.

If you want to get updated state, you must use `useEffect` hook.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";


useEffect(() => {
    console.log(details)
},[details]);
```

For more Detail about React useEffect hook refer to [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Also Refer to [Is setState() method async?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-setstate-method-async/#:%7E:text=This%20function%20is%20used%20to,remember%20that%20setState%20is%20asynchronous.) and [Change is not reflected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) and [await useState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614272/await-usestate-in-react) for more detail

Comment: It is not asynchronous - I've explained that in my answer. More details in the updated React docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

Comment: Dear @AliNauman
it's wrong
please refer to main documentation in https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
setState works Async

Comment: You've linked the documentation for the `setState` method accessible in class components, while we are talking about the function returned by `useState`. Neither the old React docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) nor the new ones (I linked earlier) say that the setter function from `useState` is asynchronous.

Comment: Functions and effects in React component are essentially closures (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), hence why the state updates feel "asynchronous" while they really are not.

Answer (score 0):

The function returned by `useState` does not update the state immediately. Instead, it tells React to queue a state update, and this will be done once all event handlers have run.

Once the component is re-rendered, you will then see the new state.

When you `console.log` right after the fetch, the component has not yet re-rendered, and hence you see `undefined`.

Comment: so how can I solve the problem? I tried useEffect but it didn't work correctly

Comment: You should rethink what you are trying to do here - you want to update a parent component's state through a child component. You normally have a parent component managing the state, while the child just renders it (received as props)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is `async`, and you placed `console.log()` after it, so there are no `props.details` at this moment. You can try to convert `openWorkOrder` to `async` function and `await` for fetched results.

Comment: when you use then and pass callback, there's no need to use async