# addDoc from firestore v9 is running before the state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
const [workout,setWorkout] = useState({
      workoutname:"",
      exercisesSelection:[],
    });
    
const SaveWorkout = async ()=>{
      setWorkout(prevArr=>{
        return {
          ...prevArr,
          workoutname:workoutName,
          exercisesSelection:currentExercises
        }
      })
      console.log(workout)
      await addDoc(workoutsCollectionRef,{
        workoutName:workout.workoutname,
        exercises:workout.exercisesSelection,
      })
      
    }
```

Documment is being added with the values empty. I believe that the state is changing after the addDoc.

[image]

Comment: *I believe that the state is changing after the addDoc.* - that is certainly the case. Do you have a question about that? Seems like you should not use the state variable in `SaveWorkout` and instead use the correct values.

Comment: How can i set the state before running the addDoc?

Comment: Is that absolutely the requirement here, or would it be enough to call addDoc with the correct values (assuming they are what you expect in `workoutName` and `currentExercises`? Please edit the question to clarify - don't leave information only in comments.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state is an asynchronous operation in ReactJS. If you have an operation that should only run after the state has been modified, use a (separate) `useEffect` hook for it. So something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  await addDoc(workoutsCollectionRef,{
    workoutName:workout.workoutname,
    exercises:workout.exercisesSelection,
  }), 
  [workout] //  ensure the code runs whenever workout has changed
);
```

Note that this is not related to the specific Firebase version, and would be the same in SDK versions 8 and before

Also see:

- [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)
- [Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)
- [await useState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614272/await-usestate-in-react)